# Button at smaller size not round with layer.cornerRadius

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cornerradius

I tried to create a button and style it with that code:

---

```
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

---

My button size was 100x100 and if I make it smaller (e.g. 80x80 as shown below) the border is not round anymore:
[image: Centered "circle" is 80x80 the other two are 100x100]

How do I get the centered circle round aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this below code

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width/2
```

Make sure height and width are equal at every time.

Comment: It worked thank you... So easy, but I didn't get it myself... Will accept your answer after the cooldown.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly set corner radius as buttonWidth/2. I assume your button is having equal width and height.

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width/2
```